# simple java incrementing not clear

Tags: java, output, increment

im trying to understand the basics of incrementing in Java...Here I have the basic example  and I'm not understanding the output of it very crearly...so it starts as 4 which is 2  * 2 of course, and 9 which is 4 * 4 + 1, but how does it get 16 now ? thank you

```
public class Mystery 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  int y;
  int x = 2;
  int total = 0;


  while ( x <= 10 ) 
  {
     y = x * x;     
     System.out.println( y );   
     total += y;              
     ++x;                        
  } 

  System.out.printf( "Total is %d\n", total );
 } // end main
 } // end class Mystery
```

output

```
  4
  9
 16
 25
 36
 49
 64
 81
 100
 Total is 384
```

Comment: "_9 which is 4 * 4 + 1_" ????? 9 is 3x3 here...

Comment: 9 is not 4*4+1, it is 3*3

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: omg thats where i got it wrong...i was looking at y instead of x..well that solves it all..thank you

Comment: This is where using a debugger to step through your code is useful in understand what it is doing.

Comment: By `[decrement]` I assumed you meant `[increment]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is incremented every iteration.

```
  x    x*x    total
--------------------
  2    2*2=4    4
  3    3*3=9    13
  4    4*4=16   29
  ...
```

This would be very easy to understand if you added more debug output:

```
  while ( x <= 10 ) 
  {
     y = x * x;       
     total += y;

     System.out.printf("x=%d    y=x*x=%d   total=%d, x, y, total );

     ++x;                        
  }
```

[image]

Comment: thank you sir...i just went full retard...looking it y instead of x

Comment: @Dana we all have those days.

Answer (score 3):

16 is 4*4, as can be expected. your algorithm prints our first 2*2, then 3*3, not 4*4+1, which would be 17 by the way.

Comment: thank you for making it clear...

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the result of this line:

```
y = x * x;
```

And you increment `x` by 1 in each iteration. This is basic multiplication:

```
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 3 = 9
4 * 4 = 16
5 * 5 = 25
...
```

and `4 * 4 + 1` is 17 *not* 9.